# Nativescript failed on build release apk success on debug.apk

Tags: android, nativescript

I tried to build Nativescript --release on android but failed. 
This is debug result:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':packageF0F1F2Release'.

> File 'D:\NativeScript\key' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' is not a file.
```

I cant find any guide to resolve this using nativescript with CLI. I can build using android studio but I prefer to use CLI. I followed this Command with nativescript v 2.52 , tns-core-module 2.51 and tns-android 2.50

```
┌─────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Usage   │ Synopsis                                                                                                              │
│ General │ $ tns build android [--compileSdk <API Level>] [--key-store-path <File Path> --key-store-password <Password> --key    │
│         │ -store-alias <Name> --key-store-alias-password <Password>] [--release] [--static-bindings] [--copy-to <File Path>]    │
└─────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

There is no problem when building debug.apk on emulator. Thank you.

Comment: Are you providing keystore/alias/keystore password with --release ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating Release build require 2 steps :

1. Create keystore file for release
2. Generate release build with the help of keystore

**Create keystore file for release**

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore file/location/where/you/want/to/save/appkeystore_ks.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias YourApplicatioNameAlias`

Ref : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually

**Generate release build with the help of keystore**

`tns build android --release --key-store-path /keystore/file/location/appkeystore_ks.jks  --key-store-password thepassword --key-store-alias YourApplicatioNameAlias --key-store-alias-password thepassword`

Ref : https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps

Regards.

Comment: Its available with android sdk.